# Do not open package source file if an error is thrown from package

Tags: pycharm

```
import os


os.path.join(None,'')
```

I have the above code and I run it in PyCharm with debug mode. Clearly an exception will be thrown from os.path.join().

PyCharm will automatically open Lib\ntpath.py and highlight the line that throws the exception.

Can I ask PyCharm not to open package source code file and let PyCharm only focus on my project  files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Debug window and click two red dots (*View Breakpoints* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>).

Then in left panel select *Any exception* from *Python Exceptions Breakpoint* and check *Ignore library files*.

[image: Breakpoints]